# How would I add rectangular boxes on top of my google maps?

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-studio, debugging

I would like to add 3 boxes on top of the `Google Map` to hold some text starting from the bottom stacked on top of each other.

Note:  `<Button>` is what I'm using to test out if anything will appear on the google maps.  It turns out that nothing appears.

Am I on the right track to achieving what I want?  What should I change?

[image]

Here's `activity_maps.xml`:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/searchBar"
            android:layout_width="289dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/searchButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:onClick="onSearch"
            android:text="SEARCH" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context="com.mancj.example.MapsActivity">
    </fragment>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, try this

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
              xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
              android:id="@+id/map"
              android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              tools:context="com.mancj.example.MapsActivity">
    </fragment>

    <LinearLayout
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

        <EditText
            android:hint="Search"
            android:id="@+id/searchBar"
            android:layout_width="289dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/searchButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:onClick="onSearch"
            android:text="SEARCH" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:id="@+id/button2"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Ah, this works!  But it's hiding behind the search button. How can I move it down so that it appears right above to white dot on the emulator and make it rectangular so it can take up the whole width?

Comment: Not entirely sure what exactly we need, but try the edited version, maybe it will help. If not, you can just manually move objects using Design window on android studio

Comment: Ok, I tried the edited version.  It's putting the box at the bottom, which is what I want.  But it's also putting the search bar and search button on the bottom as well.  

Also, I tried to move it manually in the Design tab (next to Text) but it won't let me move anything.

Comment: You can manually select them and drag them to the top if needed

Comment: Alright, so you have an edit text and a two buttons. You want edit text and a search button to be at the top, and the other button to be at the bottom, right>?